# Exception: Waited 10000 milliseconds for org.apache.drill.shaded.guava.com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@6ea2bc93[status=PENDING]]

Tags: java, netty, apache-drill

I have upgraded the Netty version in my Drill project from 4.0.48.Final to 4.1.50.Final. After up-gradation Plain authentication is working. But, I am unable to connect using SSL.
Below error is coming...

Exception: Waited 10000 milliseconds for org.apache.drill.shaded.guava.com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture@6ea2bc93[status=PENDING]]

Can somebody help with the possible solution or suggest what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Alka